# Explanation of an RGB to BGR  C++ macro

Tags: c++, macros

```
#define RGB2BGR(a_ulColor) (a_ulColor & 0xFF000000) | ((a_ulColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16) | (a_ulColor & 0x00FF00) | ((a_ulColor & 0x0000FF) << 16)
```

Can you please explain to me the meaning of this macro?

Comment: That macro is relatively trivial. In any case, you should try to better understand it yourself, or explain in greater detail what you don't understand about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Colors are usually represented by a 32-bit integer. 32-bit integers can hold four 8-bit bytes. Three of them are used to hold red, green, and blue color information. The remaining byte is either left unused or used to hold transparency information.

Which byte represents which color is not standardized. Some APIs expect the bytes like this:

```
(MSB) ******** rrrrrrrr gggggggg bbbbbbbb (LSB)
```

Which is the "RGB" layout, perhaps the most common form. In the illlustration above, the most sigificant 8-bits are the "don't care" bits, that is, the bits there are not used. The least significant 8-bits store the information for the blue color.

Some APIs expect the reverse for the 3 color bytes, like this:

```
(MSB) ******** bbbbbbbb gggggggg rrrrrrrr (LSB)
```

Which is the "BGR" layout.

The macro helps interconvert the two layouts using the bitwise operators. Let's take a look at its definition:

```
(a_ulColor & 0xFF000000) | ((a_ulColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16) |
(a_ulColor & 0x00FF00) | ((a_ulColor & 0x0000FF) << 16)
```

Let's say we have a color, [Cornflower Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornflower_blue), which has a value of 0x93CCEA. In the RGB layout, it has the following bit pattern:

```
a_ulColor = 00000000 10010011 11001100 11101010
```

The following expressions give you the following patterns:

```
1. a_ulColor & 0xFF000000 --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
2. a_ulColor & 0xFF0000   --> 00000000 10010011 00000000 00000000
3. a_ulColor & 0x00FF00   --> 00000000 00000000 11001100 00000000
4. a_ulColor & 0x0000FF   --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 11101010
```

Notices that we're just extracting the individual bytes. Expression #1 extracts the most significant 8-bits, and expression #4 extracts the least signficiant 8-bits. We were able to do this via [the `AND` bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Now, to convert RGB to BGR, we have to move some bits left or right, via [bitshifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). Like this:

```
1. (a_ulColor & 0xFF000000)     --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
2. (a_ulColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16 --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 10010011
3. (a_ulColor & 0x00FF00)       --> 00000000 00000000 11001100 00000000
4. (a_ulColor & 0x0000FF) << 16 --> 00000000 11101010 00000000 00000000
```

The expression `a >> 16` simply shifts the bits to the right by 16 bits. `a << 16` shifts the bits to the left by 16 bits.

Then, when you [`OR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) them all together, you get this:

```
00000000 11101010 11001100 10010011
```

Compare the result to the original bit pattern:

```
00000000 11101010 11001100 10010011
00000000 10010011 11001100 11101010
```

You can see that the 2nd and 4th bytes are swapped. That's all the macro does.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a four-byte integral value, `AA BB CC DD`, and returns the value `AA DD CC BB`. You can see that the first and third byte are retained unchanged, while the second byte is moved down two bytes (`>> 16`) and the fourth is moved up by two (`<< 16`).

Answer (score 0):

It swaps the order of the byte-sized RGB elements from RGB to BGR (and vice-versa, to be fair).

Answer (score 0):

`a_ulColor` is a 32 bit RGB representation (e.g. of a pixel or bitmap). The macro converts it to BGR layout. It effectively produces a new value by swapping the Red and Blue component values.